# Ubuntu slow in lenovo s215

Tags: ati, amd-processor

I just bought a lenovo netbook, the spec is
AMD E1 2100 1.4Ghz with HD 8210
RAM 2GB

is it make sense with that spec my ubuntu is running slow? or is there anything i can do to make my ubuntu run faster?

sometimes when i browse the internet and page is loading the cursor is blinking.

i use ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Gnome classic as my desktop environment (it was gnome 3, but it is really slow like a snail)

Comment: Do you run Ubuntu 12.04.4 32bit or Ubuntu 64bit? The 32bit version should run just fine on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with Unity as default desktop environment. You can always switch back to a lightweight desktop just as I did. I had installed Ubuntu on VMWare with Windows 7 host and it was running slow. After switching to Xfce desktop environment, everything is now working fine. (although a little less graphical effect).

You can switch to **Xfce** desktop by opening terminal and typing

*sudo apt-get install xfce4*

Source: [3 best Linux desktop environment](http://www.beopensource.com/2014/04/3-best-linux-desktop-environment-for-you.html)